# C, initialize struct without malloc

Tags: c, oop, constructor, struct

I would avoid the use of malloc to initialize a structure and I'm looking for the best practice for the design a C software using an oo-style (where possible).

**Only C99, not C++**

First question, what is preferable when use a struct like an object? typedef its pointer or not?

These are my test(all works using gcc compiler):

**case 1**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct sItem{
    int n;
    char* text;
} oItem, *Item;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Item i1=(&(oItem){.n=1, .text="A"});
    Item i2=(&(oItem){.n=100, .text="ABC"});
    printf("%d, %s, %d\n", i1->n, i1->text, sizeof(*i1)); // 1, "A", 8
    printf("%d, %s, %d\n", i2->n, i2->text, sizeof(*i2)); // 1, "ABC", 8
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

This works, but i think it should not because text is not initialized to contains strings.
Is this an invalid piece of code?

**case 2**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct sItem{
    int n;
    char text[5];
} oItem, *Item;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Item i1=(&(oItem){.n=1, .text="A"});
    Item i2=(&(oItem){.n=100, .text="ABC"});
    printf("%d, %s, %d\n", i1->n, i1->text, sizeof(*i1)); // 1, "A", 12
    printf("%d, %s, %d\n", i2->n, i2->text, sizeof(*i2)); // 1, "ABC", 12
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

This works and I think it is correct, is it?

**case 3**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define Item_new(i, n, s) (&(oItem){0});Item_ctor(i, n, s);
#define Item_neww(i, x, s) (&(oItem){\
        .n=x,\
        .text=s\
})

typedef struct sItem{
    int n;
    char text[5];
} oItem, *Item;


void Item_ctor(Item i, int n, char* text){
    i->n=n;
    strcpy(i->text, text);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Item i1=Item_new(i1, 10, "ABC");
    Item i2=Item_neww(i2, 10, "ABC");
    printf("%d, %s, %d\n", i1->n, i1->text, sizeof(*i1)); // 10, "ABC", 12
    printf("%d, %s, %d\n", i2->n, i2->text, sizeof(*i2)); // 10, "ABC", 12
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I think this is very nice, but hides the code, and perhaps might be harmful, what do you think?
I case 3, what is the best choice: macro or constructor function?

Comment: Examples 1 & 2 are NOT valid code. You cannot take the address of a temporary and expect it to contain a valid value. Use alloca instead if you want a stack-allocated pointer.

Comment: 2 is valid, why do you say it isn't?

Comment: Because you take the address of a temporary value, which is undefined behavior.

Comment: In case 2 i don't use the address of a temporary value...

Comment: I wouldn't typedef a pointer with a name that doesn't reflect that it is a pointer. If Item_ptr is too long, I would just use Item *.

Comment: If I do: "printf("%p\n",&oItem);" I get  and error "unexpected type name", which lines up with my understanding of what  oItem is - a type. I am confused by how you are using it as a variable and taking it's address.

Comment: I don't use oItem like a variable, where do you see that?

Comment: @blow Oh, maybe it is {} being cast to an oItem and the address of that being taken. I looked at &(oItem) as taking the address of oItem. Now it does look like a cast of a {}. Would like to know what a {} resolves to. But I believe &(oItem){} is what was being referred to as the address of a temporary.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII, why do you think that taking the address of a compound literal is UB? This is C and not C++. Compound literals have a lifetime just as other variables, that is to the end of the enclosing block. Not only in the scope of the expression, as it would be in C++

Comment: Case 1 is valid for the same reasons that `char* s = "ABC";` is valid, right?  As long as you don't try to change the pointed-to characters.

Comment: @aschepler, right. For 1 it would certainly be better specify that field as `char const*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do 3, macros that contain unprotected `;` make me extremely nervous.

Instead I would replace your "new" and "ctor" by the following

```
#define Item_new(i, n, s) Item_ctor(&(oItem){0}, n, s)

Item Item_ctor(Item i, int n, char* text){
    if (i) {
      i->n=n;
      strncpy(i->text, text, 4);
    }
    return i;
}
```

This doesn't break the expectation of the user for `Item_new`: a real
function like macro that returns a value.

And the ctor should do the necessary checks and never overwrite the memory, `i->text[4]` will always be `0`. (Better would be to have a symbolic constant instead of `5` and use it also for the `strncpy` call.)

Answer (score 1):

Case 3 is that I see mostly and would recommend. Wrapping the code in a constructor function is perfectly fine - why hiding code would be a problem? In fact, that's a feature - hide the interface from the implementation. Also, don't use macros for that - this is a way too complicated task for a macro, and nevertheless, macros are often evil.

Approach 1 and 2 are extremely ugly (as it turns out, they are also UB) and unreadable in my opinion. Case 1 is, furthermore, not const correct, either use case 2 instead (well, don't use it either because it invokes undefined behaviour) or declare "text" as `const char *`.

Comment: Thank you, in case 3, using macros is a more efficent way to initialize struct because i use literal struct compound initialization, using ctor i have first to initialize all struct data to 0 (using {0}) and after set them, is this true? thank again

Comment: @blow it's either not least efficient or the deficency is as small as it doesn't worth composing and maintaining such a macro.

Comment: In an embedded device with poor perfomance and a very little amount of memory wich would you choice?

Comment: Ok thank you, I will follow the direction you suggested, but i have some doubt in what i'm try to do, I think I'm wrong to choose the design pattern like OO, but for this i will open a new thread maybe. thank again.

Comment: @H2C03 In example 3, Where does the data that the two pointers in main are pointing to, reside?

Comment: Why would 1 and 2 be UB? Taking the address of a compound literal in the way this is done here is perfectly legal.